# displayFor first item of list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and in my code behind I have a list of dates that has a foreach loop in it and adds a new item of something.

But I just want to get the first item.

So I've been doing  `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllDates)` but of course that listed all the dates. I tried using the placeholder, which I think would work but not sure I got the syntax right?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllDates{1})
```

I dont want to add a forloop, I already have that in the code behind. Surely I can do this in the front?

Comment: use square brackets if it implements `IList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reference an item in your collection by index, so I would just change your curly braces to square brackets and you should be on the right track.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllDates[1])
```

Comment: if you want take the first element is better @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllDates.FirstOrDefault()) or @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllDates[0])

Comment: Title says first, but the question says second, I went with the text of the question, but I agree with you.  Also, this could use some Null checking in case there is no second array element as well.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing title. I will change this. As for the null check, there is already one in the code behind. The DateTime is nullable.